# Flood analysis using Arcgis

Tags: gis, hec-ras

Hi every one I am using HEC-GeoRAS 10.1 for ArcGIS 10.1 and HEC-RAS 4.1.0, after performing the HEC-GeoRAS basic tutorial I successfully exported the GIS layer for HEC-RAS now when i import this layer in HEC-RAS it shows an error 'Runtime error 9, subscript out of range'.

Can any one help me in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling ApFramework.

Read this (last post):

http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1149&t=249290

Comment: I have deleted the for Water Utility (containg apframework) placed in C:/Program file/ESRI.. and restarted my machine but this still doesn't solve my problem. when i import the gisToras.sdf files in Hecras the error remains there...